# Is there an alternative to deepfreeze?

Tags: windows, windows-7, antivirus

I am managing 20 units computer rental shop running in Windows 7, which primarily caters online gaming like DOTA 2, League of Legends, Crossfire, RAN Online, etc which is being updated constantly twice a week.

My current setup is I have deepfreeze installed. We are using deepfreeze to prevent viruses from spreading rather than an antivirus coz its easier to restart the computer rather than do a scan all the time. Whenever there are game updates, we turn off deepfreeze and restart the computer, then we install all updates, then turn on again deepfreeze and restart the computer again.

I think there is a method that you can add an exclusions folder where it will not be monitored by deepfreeze but my worry is that might be also an entry point of a virus.

Is there other kind of software recommendations / setup aside from the one that I am doing now?

Comment: What OS?  Gratis or commercial?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Carl talks about viruses, so most likely that's Windows :) But yes, Carl: Can you confirm, please? And any budget to name?

Comment: Yes, I'm using windows 7 pro, budget for each workstation is around 50$

Comment: @CarlAlberto Are you only looking for one time payment, or are subscriptions also accepted? I had [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/index.php?CommercialUse) in mind ($47.95 per computer per year)

Comment: Yearly fee, would be a good option but any lowest Year over year cost would be great to consider, haven't heard of sandboxie but will try to consider it later on, Thanks for the suggestion @Timmy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](https://alternativeto.net/software/deep-freeze/) lists 13 active alternatives to Deep Freeze on Windows.

> With [Shadow Defender](https://alternativeto.net/software/shadow-defender/), you have the flexibility to specify which files
>   and folders are permanently saved to the real environment. This
>   ensures important files and folders are kept after a reboot.

Note that with physical access, only full disk encryption can keep your files safe.

Personally, i'd re-image all rented disks and even the firmware if possible, plus check for hardware keyloggers.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Reboot Restore Rx](http://www.horizondatasys.com/en/products_and_solutions.aspx?ProductId=18#Features).  I use it.  It's similar to Deep Freeze, but it's free.  The only problem is no exclusion drive.

I think you could invest in external storage solution since it's free, but that's just my thinking.